# UserWarning: Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete warnings.warn("Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete") Python

Tags: python, sql, apache-kafka

Why the script sends only 100 data and calls error?
I think it must continue after committing the first 100 rows because it stays in the loop

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:756: UserWarning: Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete
warnings.warn("Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete")

```
def parse(d,param):
    r={}
    if str(type(d)) == "<class 'dict'>":
        return (d)
    return -1



s_con = pymysql.connect(host="xxx", user="xxxx", password="xxxx"}, port=3306,
                                db="xxx", cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)
s_cur = s_con.cursor()
s_con.commit()
s_cur.execute("select id, name from table") 


while True:
    num_rows = 0
    st = datetime.now()
    r = [dict((s_cur.description[i][0], value) \
              for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in s_cur.fetchmany(100)]  
    print(r)
    for d in r:
        j = parse(d, param)
        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="xxxxx",
                                 value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v, default = myconverter).encode('utf-8'), )
        print(producer)
        print(j)
        num_rows = num_rows + 1
        if j != -1:
            print(param["TOPIC"])
            producer.send(param["TOPIC"], value=j)  
    s_con.commit()
    time.sleep(10)

    if not r:
        break


finally:
s_cur.close() 
s_con.close() 
producer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

just like the message tells you, the previous unbuffered result was left incomplete

it's just a waring, you don't have to take it serious.

the root cause is you are using

```py
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSCursor
```

How many records do you have?
if not too many, you can use regular cursor.