# handle apostrophes with tuple generator into sql query

Tags: python, mysql

I use a library that is fed thousands of tuples from a cursor.
The data should not really be altered on the way IN to the library

```
full_data = ((row[id], row) for row in read_cursor)
my_generator = deduper.fingerprinter(full_data)
```

The return from that generator is actually a tuple of 2 strings eg. ('asdfadfg','kjlkj') similar to what was sent in.  It has thousands to return with each iteration.

I use it with an 'executemany' sql insert like this:

`write_cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (%s, %s)", my_generator)`

This works great.. until an apostrophe appears in the tuples.

How do I escape them here?  I cant figure out where i can replace the apostrophe with 2. Im not too familiar with handling tuples via a generator.

Comment: You don't need to escape anything. `cursor.execute()` handles this automatically.

Comment: You would have this problem if you were doing string formatting instead of using `cursor.execute()` parameters.

Comment: hmm.. thats what i thought.. but i replaced this method with a more basic one where i just concatenate all the tuples together into a single insert statement, and replace the apostrophes with 2, and it works fine..    when i use the above, it doesn't finish inserting them all

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: "Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete" .. it doesnt actually halt the program as its just a warning.. but i see that only a fraction of the inserts occur

Comment: This works:                all_rows = ''
                for x, y in my_generator:
                    all_rows += ' ROW("{}", "{}"),'.format(x, y)
                all_rows = all_rows.replace("'", "''")  # handle quotes in data
                all_rows = all_rows[:-1]

                                db.execute( "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES " + all_rows)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122060/userwarning-previous-unbuffered-result-was-left-incomplete-warnings-warnprevi

Comment: seems very similar.. but no real answer / cause... other than maybe use a different cursor type? insteresting.. i'll take a look at options there

Comment: As they mention there, it's just a warning, it shouldn't cause problems in the DB.

Comment: all i can say is that something is stopping the inserts with no error other than that warning maybe.. Guess it might not be the apostrophe.   So I'll look into if the type of cursor is somehow not being friendly with thousands of commands to 'executemany'.

Comment: It might be the large size of the list being sent to `executemany()`. Try breaking it up into smaller batches. `itertools.islice()` will be helpful for this.